# Running PHP using Cron

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I have a PHP file that sends email.

Now what I need is for this PHP file to send email every hour. I tried Cron with Linux (Ubuntu).

I have the line:

```
0 * * * * /var/etc/apache2/php(source of the php.ini file) /var/www/name_of_folder/mailer.php
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me? I'm new with Cron jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the php binary, not a configuration file. The default location of the PHP command line binary on ubuntu is `/usr/bin/php`, so try this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/name_of_folder/mailer.php
```

If you don't have a PHP binary (you can find out the location with `which php`) you may have to install the CLI package

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Comment: I'm tryin it tough i didn't see any php binary in the /usr/bin :(

Comment: I think PHP should be in the PATH on ubuntu, so unless you've compiled a specific version of php to run with this script, i think you could just use `0 * * * * php /var/www/name_of_folder/mailer.php`

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 never assume that the cron daemon has the same PATH (or other environment variables) as your user.

Comment: But the ubuntu server can already run php files. do i still need to install another one?

Comment: If you want to run PHP scripts from the command line, as crond does, you need the command line interface. You can't use the apache module for this.

Comment: Ok i think i get you. Sad thing is it's a company server, and I'm just an intern -.- . So i can't install anything.

Comment: The Ubuntu server can't run PHP files without php-cli; the Apache webserver can (typically via mod_php) ..... that's a major difference

Comment: ok i didn't know that...thank you for that :D. i just did the installation. :D

Comment: Hey guys! it's still not working. it's not sending the email. but when i open the mailer.php in the browser, it sends he email

Answer (score 0):

Providing this script is only for CLI/cron purposes

Find out where your PHP binary is using `which php`

copy the output.

At the start of your mailer.php script add a shebang:
`#!/path/to/php`

chmod your mailer.php to `755`

then you don't need to use the php binary in the crontab, just the path to the mailer.php script:

`0 * * * * /var/www/name_of_folder/mailer.php`